# Running Neptune in Jupyter Notebook gives NameError that Neptune is not defined

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, nameerror, mlops, neptune

```
# Create run in project (Neptune)
run = neptune.init(project='ssraghuvanshi1989/GCI-01-Lung-CT-Segmentation-20220506')
```

---

```
NameError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27104/3392926562.py in <module>
      1 # Create run in project
----> 2 run = neptune.init(project='ssraghuvanshi1989/GCI-01-Lung-CT-Segmentation-20220506')

NameError: name 'neptune' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you import it first? e.g. `import neptune.new as neptune`

Comment: Yes, I have imported the neptune.new

Answer (score 0):

Prince here from neptune.ai,

Before you start make sure you have Neptune installed by running the following pip command:

`pip install neptune-client`

Then as @John Morton suggested you have to import Neptune in your python script.
`import neptune.new as neptune`

Docs: https://docs.neptune.ai/getting-started/hello-world

Let me know if this helps you